# bare bones MembershipProvider in sitecore

Tags: asp.net-membership, sitecore, membership-provider

I'm trying to implement a really really simple MembershipProvider for sitecore, but i'm not sure if it's *too* simple to actually work. Basically we already have a custom store for user data so i know that a customer `MembershipProvider` is the way to go. However my app will not log anyone in, a different part of the system is responsible for that. Also, it doesn't care who exactly is logged in, just whether they are or aren't (the who part is irrelevant in the content area of my site).

So what is the best way to go about this? I am passed a token in the HTTP header which allows me to identify whether someone is logged in or not (i could even use this to actually find out who the customer is if i so wished) - don't worry it's encrypted.

I've read through the sitecore docs but they all deal with full implementations of `MembershipProvider`s.

So is it possible to actually have a membership provider that does only this i.e. returns either a user to signify being logged or an "anonymous" user for those who are logged out? it need not be concerned with anything else - password reset, look up users by email and all that jazz.

Thanks,
Nick

EDIT: with the help of Jens below i have eschewed a full-blown `MembershipProvider` in favour of a more lightweight approach.

this is what i have so far, the problem being that users are not kept logged in over multiple requests.

```
public class TokenLogin : HttpRequestProcessor
{


    #region Overrides of HttpRequestProcessor

    /// <summary>
    /// Processes the specified args.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">The args.</param>
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        var customer = SomeCodeToParseAndValidateToken();

        //customer is null if token is invalid or missing
        if(customer == null || Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated) return;

        CreateVirtualUser(customer);
    }

    private static void CreateVirtualUser(CustomerAccount customer)
    {
        string userName = "extranet\\" + customer.CustomerAccountId;

        User userItem = AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(userName, true);   
        userItem.Profile.Initialize(userName, true);    
        userItem.Profile.Save();

        AuthenticationManager.Login(userItem.Name);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implementing a membershipprovider is a lot of work for what you seem to need. If I were you I would implement a scenario, where you create a virtual user everytime someone needs to be logged in.
So the logic would be to check if a user has your token, then create a virtual user, log the virtual user in and you should be good to go.

Here is a guide on the virual user thingie: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Security/Faking%20user%20roles/Virtual%20user.aspx

EDIT: The code in the link is depricated. Here is how you add virtual users:

```
   userName = "extranet\\"+userName    
   User userItem = AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(userName, true);   
   userItem.Profile.Initialize(userName, true);    
   userItem.Profile.Email = userName + "@yourdomain.com";   
   userItem.Profile.Save();

   AuthenticationManager.Login(userItem.Name)
```

EDIT 2: I have the following code:

```
    public class TestVirtualUserProcessor : HttpRequestProcessor
    {


      public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
      {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Sitecore.Context.User.Name + "<br/>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated + "<br/>");

        CreateVirtualUser("jenneren");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Sitecore.Context.User.Name + "<br/>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated + "<br/>");
        }

      private static void CreateVirtualUser(string name)
      {
        string userName = "extranet\\" + name;

        User userItem = AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(userName, true);
        userItem.Profile.Initialize(userName, true);
        userItem.Profile.Save();

        AuthenticationManager.Login(userItem.Name);
      }


    }
```

This outputs the following the first time I hit the frontend:

extranet\Anonymous
False
extranet\jenneren
True

And the second time I hit the frontend I get:

extranet\jenneren
True
extranet\jenneren
True

So it should work.
Cheers
Jens

Comment: Wow, thanks Jens :) at what point would i do this? in the pipeline somewhere? btw i love your learnsitecore website!

Comment: It depend on your login mechanism. If you have a loginscreen I would simply put it here. If you have some sort of SSO, where the user is validated as soon as they hit the site through a token I would probably add it to the httpBeginRequestPipeline (only run the processor if the user isAnonymous)

Comment: yes, we are using a kind of SSO approach, using a token as you described. i'll get on this and let you know the results. what did you mean by "only run if the user isAnonymous"? Is there a way to completely skip the pipeline step, or do you literally mean wrap in the above code in an `if` statement? Sorry if my questions are elementary, never delved into the sitecore pipelines much!

Comment: No worries. I meant having an if statement at the top eg. if(!isAnonymous)) return;. The reason is that when you hook into the httpBeginRequest pipeline, the code will run on every request on every ressource requested, so you don't want to create a virtual user each time.

Comment: Oh, I wish I'd read about this approach for something I was implementing a while ago, specifically using this approach with my active directory users instead of creating a membership provider. Good answer Jens.

Comment: @Jens, presumably the value of `isAuthenticated` is calculated by me, rather than some property on the sitecore `Context`?

Comment: I would use the Sitecore.Context.User.IsAnonymous. this is only true if the current user is domain\Anonymous, and that is when you want to create your virtual user. Don't know if that makes sense?

Comment: makes perfect sense. i think i'll combine that with my token logic `if(tokenNotPresentOrInvalid || Sitecore.Context.User.IsAnonymous) return;` so i run the minimal code every time. Just implementing, will mark as answer if it all checks out nicely :-)

Comment: Jens, i've now implemented this and it appears to be working apart fine. One small detail though, this login should be persisted across requests but i am not seeing that behaviour. The virtual user is considered authenticated for the duration of one request, but is back to being unauthenticated in the next request. maybe i'm just getting the wrong end of the stick (it still works regardless!). 

Also, there is no property `Sitecore.Context.User.IsAnonymous`, the correct property is `Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated` (it's just the inverse :-))

Comment: Hmmm... It should be persisted through multiple requests. Can you share some code? On second request what is Sitecore.Context.User.Name

Comment: I'll add the code to my question as it's impractical to demonstrate it in this small box. The name is appearing as `extranet\anonymous` on any subsequent request.

Comment: I just tried it out. It works fine on my machine. Remember to plug it in after the userresolver in the pipeline

Comment: that sounds like the issue! i had it plugged in after item resolver! is this what you were expecting? `<processor type="Cms.Utils.Pipelines.HttpRequest.TokenLogin, Cms.Utils"                   patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.UserResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']" />`

Comment: unless the above xml is incorrect (it hasn't thrown any exceptions!), it is still not working - a user is not kept logged in across multiple requests (they are re-logged in each time)

Comment: Obviously this is an old post, but on the off chance that someone is attempting this approach, has anyone figured out the issue of it losing the user after each request? I am experiencing the exact same problem as WickyNilliams. Is there some config setting to indicate that virtual users should exist for the duration of the session?