# SiteCore .Net Membership example

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, asp.net-membership, sitecore

I have been working with SiteCore 7 for about a month or less.

I am unable to set up a .Net Membership provider from an external database in it.

This is what my class looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace MProvider
{
    public abstract class MemberProvider : MembershipProvider
    {
        public override void Initialize(string name,        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
    {
        base.Initialize(name, config);
    }

    public override MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
}
}
```

This is the web.config in SiteCore

```
<switchingProviders>
      <membership>
        <provider providerName="sql" storeFullNames="true" wildcard="%" domains="*"/>
        <provider providerName="MProvider" storeFullNames="true" wildcard="%"     domains="*"/>

    <membership defaultProvider="sitecore" hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Security.SitecoreMembershipProvider,     Sitecore.Kernel" realProviderName="MProvider" providerWildcard="%" raiseEvents="true"/>
        <add name="sql" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"   connectionStringName="core" applicationName="sitecore" minRequiredPasswordLength="1"   minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"   requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="256"/>
        <add name="MProvider"  type="Sitecore.Security.SitecoreMembershipProvider"   realProviderName="MProvider"
        applicationName="sitecore" minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
        minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"></add>
      </providers>
    </membership>}
```

My questions are:

1. has anyone ever worked with a .Net Membership Provider in SiteCore?
   a. if so, what am I doing wrong?
2. does anyone know of a working example of a .Net Membership in SiteCore?

Much appreciated !

Dave

Comment: The type attribute of the MProvider membership provider... shouldn't that point to your new custom class?  Also... I take it your membership provider has some actual code in it?

Comment: Bartlomiejs answer is right. However you could consider if you really need a membershipprovider. Consider using virtual users instead, as I have described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159731/bare-bones-membershipprovider-in-sitecore/7160386#7160386

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few days ago I implemented membership provider and role provider to allow users from external database with specific role to login into sitecore. That answer helped me alot. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6954337/421490

Here is my membership provider implementation. I cleaned this class. All other methods and properties are overriden and throws NotImplementedException.

```
public class FrontEndMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
    var webSecurity = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IWebSecurity>();

    var cleanUsername = CleanUsername(this.Name, username);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cleanUsername))
    {
        return webSecurity.ValidateUser(cleanUsername, password) != null;
    }

    return false;
}

public override MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)
{
    var usersRepository = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUsersRepository>();

    var user = usersRepository.GetById((int)providerUserKey);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return this.CreateMembershipUser(user);
}

public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
{
    var usersRepository = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUsersRepository>();

    var cleanUsername = CleanUsername(this.Name, username);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cleanUsername))
    {
        var user = usersRepository.GetByEmail(cleanUsername);
        if (user != null)
        {
            return this.CreateMembershipUser(user);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public override MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
{
    var usersRepository = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUsersRepository>();
    var membershipUserCollection = new MembershipUserCollection();

    var allUsersWithRole = usersRepository.GetAllUsersForSitecore(pageIndex + 1, pageSize);
    foreach (var user in allUsersWithRole)
    {
        membershipUserCollection.Add(this.CreateMembershipUser(user));
    }

    totalRecords = allUsersWithRole.TotalItemCount;

    return membershipUserCollection;
}

private MembershipUser CreateMembershipUser(User user)
{
    return new MembershipUser(this.Name, UpgradeUsername(this.Name, user.Email), user.Id, user.Email, null, null, user.UserAccountStateId == (int)UserAccountStateType.Active, user.UserAccountStateId == (int)UserAccountStateType.Banned, user.CreationDate, user.LastActivityDate ?? user.CreationDate, user.LastActivityDate ?? user.CreationDate, user.CreationDate, user.CreationDate);
}

public static string CleanUsername(string domain, string username)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
    {
        if (username.Contains("\\"))
        {
            var parts = username.Split('\\');
            return parts[0] == domain ? parts[1] : null;
        }
    }

    return username;
}

public static string UpgradeUsername(string domain, string username)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
    {
        if (username.Contains("\\"))
        {
            var parts = username.Split('\\');
            if (parts[0] == domain)
            {
                return username;
            }
        }

        return domain + "\\" + username;

    }

    return username;
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you Bartlomiej for the post.  @Jens-Mikkelson I am going to ask my Boss about that today.  This is for an intranet project so I dont know if we want users adding themselves to our system.  I may be not understanding the concept of virtual users in sitecore however.