# Sitecore restrict access to areas of a site based on (external) user's role

Tags: asp.net-membership, sitecore, sitecore6

I have set up a Sitecore instance with an external ASP.NET membership database (for info on this see my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945187/sitecore-authenticate-users-against-external-membership-database)) and can successfully create and edit users on the site (not using the Sitecore User Manager).  However, the location elements I've set up in the web config (under `<configuration>` don't seem to be having any effect - I can access all areas irrespective of whether I'm logged in or not.  I'm not sure if I'm meant to include an  `<authorization>` element under `<system.web>` - I've tried this and it still has no effect.

FYI I have under `<configuration>` in web.config:

```
<location path="en/administrators">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Administrator"/>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

**UPDATE**

Just to summarise some of what was mentioned in the Sitecore security reference manual; it is necessary to deny read access to the 'extranet\Anonymous' user account to the relevant pages.  This is done within the Security Editor in sitecore.  Note also that it's necessary to perform a publish for these changes to become active (unlike changes to sitecore editor accounts which become active straight away).

Comment: Use Sitecore authorization. It's all implemented and based on users and roles in Sitecore. There is documentation available on how to implement role based security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have implemented a Membership Provider, you should not set security through configuration, but through the Sitecore backend interface. Sitecore has it's own way of implementing access, and it uses that approach even though you have implemented your own membership provider.

So in the shell you should open the security editor and only allow access for the role you want.

Also take a look at the Security Refernece guide http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Security%20Reference.aspx

Comment: D'oh! As usual I overlooked the simple solution while trying to work out a complicated one... Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Use Sitecore authorization. It's all implemented and based on users and roles in Sitecore. There is documentation available on how to implement role based security. When you are bound the for example Active Directory users you should probably write something to import the AD users to Sitecore and set roles there, as Sitecore has it's own security layer.