# Problem integrating members from an Umbraco site into Sitecore using the UmbracoMembershipProvider

Tags: c#, sitecore, umbraco

The rundown is we currently have a site based on Umbraco v4.6.1 with its list of members and would like to integrate those members into our Sitecore v6.5 instance under its own domain using the standard UmbracoMembershipProvider.

To do that, we've added the appropriate connection string as well as these entries in the web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="sitecore" hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Security.SitecoreMembershipProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" realProviderName="switcher" providerWildcard="%" raiseEvents="true" />
    <add name="sql" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="core" applicationName="sitecore" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="256" />
    <add name="switcher" type="Sitecore.Security.SwitchingMembershipProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" applicationName="sitecore" mappings="switchingProviders/membership" />
    <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Another Type" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

and

```
<switchingProviders>
  <membership>
    <provider providerName="UmbracoMembershipProvider" storeFullNames="false" wildcard="%" domains="umbraco" />
    <provider providerName="sql" storeFullNames="true" wildcard="%" domains="*" />
  </membership>
  <roleManager>
    <provider providerName="sql" storeFullNames="true" wildcard="%" domains="*" />
  </roleManager>
  <profile>
    <provider providerName="sql" storeFullNames="true" wildcard="%" domains="*" />
  </profile>
</switchingProviders>
```

Then, we referenced  the following required dll's from Umbraco:

- businesslogic.dll
- cms.dll
- interfaces.dll
- Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.dll
- umbraco.DataLayer.dll
- umbraco.providers.dll

Now when we try to run Sitecore, it throws a StackOverflowException from mscorlib.dll.

Does anyone have any idea of what could be happening here?

EDIT: The StackOverflowException is thrown from IIS (w3wp.exe). The 2 events logged is:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.237, time stamp: 0x4dd2333e
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x000000000064ca10
Faulting process id: 0x1f1c
Faulting application start time: 0x01cc73fe843e74e0
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: da1c3356-dff1-11e0-bab2-2c27d72da698
```

and

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
Faulting module name: mscorlib.ni.dll, version: 4.0.30319.237, time stamp: 0x4dd2341f
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x000000000039b7ef
Faulting process id: 0x1874
Faulting application start time: 0x01cc73fe9ec4bb9f
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\mscorlib\8f7f691aa155c11216387cf3420d9d1b\mscorlib.ni.dll
Report Id: df3e3c39-dff1-11e0-bab2-2c27d72da698
```

Comment: See if this can help, step by step: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945187/sitecore-authenticate-users-against-external-membership-database/6954337#6954337. BTW, it seems for your case 'storeFullNames' should be false, I doubt the Umbraco storage keeps users in the format 'domain\username'

Comment: @yan I've looked through your step by step guide and have already covered all the steps. As you've pointed out the 'storeFullNames', you are right and I've updated that to false. The wildcard should also be '%' which I have changed but I'm still getting the stackoverflow error.

Comment: Can you update your question with the stack trace?

Comment: @yan The exception thrown puts IIS into a stackoverflow state where the stack trace is lost ({Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}). Also, I probably should have mentioned that the error occurs in w3wp.exe and not Sitecore.

Comment: To be honest, I don't have an idea how to troubleshoot this... If you have an account and appropriate permissions, I would suggest contacting Sitecore Support (http://support.sitecore.net) with this problem...

Comment: I have seen something like this, when there are roles in roles that point to each other, so that you have circles in your role hierarchy. Can you check this directly in the membership database?

Comment: @yan Thanks for your effort, I'll try that.

Comment: @jens I'm using the default sitecore role provider and have not added any roles other than the install defaults. I'll try adding the Umbraco role provider and get back to you.

Comment: @jens I've tested with the UmbracoRoleProvider against a default install of Umbraco `<add name="UmbracoRoleProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoRoleProvider" />` and checked for circular roles (default install has no roles defined). I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Hmmm... The Sitecore Role Provider isn't a standard role provider, as it has the roles in roles stuff. I am not sure how to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this question is a little old, but you may want to try and add a setting to your  element called umbracoDbDSN - this is the primary entry point into the Umbraco SQL store, and it's what the UmbracoMembershipProvider uses - **not** the connectionStrings section (which, yes, is a known issue, and is a work-in-progress in future Umbraco development roadmaps).