# asp.net membership sitecore

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, sitecore

I'm migrating a ASP.NET website to Sitecore 7.  I have a login page for external users to login to my website.  I'm trying to access an external aspnetdb to do this authentication.  I have followed what is in this post:

[Sitecore authenticate users against external membership database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945187/sitecore-authenticate-users-against-external-membership-database/6954337#6954337?newreg=5a56fd7b416c45f99376e2a457a9bf16)

When I try and call the GetUser method I get a null value.  Furthermore, when I go to my User Manager I don't see any of my users located in the aspnetdb.

My configuration is outlined below:

I added a connection string to my ConnectionsStrings.config:

```
  <add name="test" connectionString="user id=***;password=***;Data Source=localhost;Database=aspnetdb"/>
```

In my web.config I added membership and role provider definitions:

```
<membership defaultProvider="sitecore" hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Security.SitecoreMembershipProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" realProviderName="switcher" providerWildcard="%" raiseEvents="true"/>
    <add name="sql" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="core" applicationName="sitecore" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="256"/>
    <add name="switcher" type="Sitecore.Security.SwitchingMembershipProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" applicationName="sitecore" mappings="switchingProviders/membership"/>
    <add name="testProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="test" applicationName="sitecore" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="256"/> 
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="sitecore" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Security.SitecoreRoleProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" realProviderName="switcher" raiseEvents="true"/>
    <add name="sql" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="core" applicationName="sitecore"/>
    <add name="switcher" type="Sitecore.Security.SwitchingRoleProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" applicationName="sitecore" mappings="switchingProviders/roleManager"/>
    <add name="testProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="test" applicationName="sitecore"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Then I added my domain switcher mappings:

```
<switchingProviders>
      <membership>
        <provider providerName="sql" storeFullNames="true" wildcard="%" domains="*"/>
        <provider providerName="testProvider" storeFullNames="false" wildcard="%" domains="extranet"/>
      </membership>
      <roleManager>
        <provider providerName="sql" storeFullNames="true" wildcard="%" domains="*"/>
         <provider providerName="testProvider" storeFullNames="false" wildcard="%" domains="extranet"/>

      </roleManager>
      <profile>
        <provider providerName="sql" storeFullNames="true" wildcard="%" domains="*"/>
      </profile>
    </switchingProviders>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I noticed from the other article link you mentioned, there was a reference to creating a new domain and modifying the domain provider. Did you also make these changes?

Comment: @mark I have tried with both a new domain and the extranet domain that already exists...i get the same results with both.

Answer (score 3):

In your membership and roleprovider definitions you need to change the defaultProvider to switcher. This means that when Sitecore is trying to identify which provider to use, it will use the configuration in your switchingproviders.

Also I think you should change the order of your switchingproviders so that the "extranet" is higher then your catch all "*".

Edit this configuration works on my environment:

```
<membership defaultProvider="switcher" hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="Extranet" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="Extranet" applicationName="sitecore" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"/>
        <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Security.SitecoreMembershipProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" realProviderName="sql" providerWildcard="%" raiseEvents="true" />
        <add name="sql" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="core" applicationName="sitecore" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="256" />
        <add name="switcher" type="Sitecore.Security.SwitchingMembershipProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" applicationName="sitecore" mappings="switchingProviders/membership" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

And for the switchingProvider:

```
<switchingProviders>
      <membership>
        <provider providerName="Extranet" storeFullNames="false" wildcard="%" domains="extranet" />
        <provider providerName="sql" storeFullNames="true" wildcard="%" domains="*" />
      </membership>
```

If you get Extranet\Anonymous back and this user isn't in your custom database you are actually using the standard Sitecore database. Make sure that the defaultProvider is set to "switcher" and that you have your provider in the swithcing provider first and that it mentions extranet.

Also make sure, that your provider set "storeFullNames" correctly. If your database doesn't contain the domain (eg. extranet\myUser) then it should be set to false.

Comment: I tried doing both suggestions and it didn't work.  According to the documentation we are supposed to leave the defaultProvider as sitecore and change the sitecore provider realProviderName to switcher.

Comment: I'm looking at the logs under the Data folder and I don't see any errors. When I make a call to Domain.GetUsers() I only get the "extranet\anonymous" user.

Comment: Any other ideas what could be wrong?  Been stuck on this for more than a few days now.

Comment: I have added my example configuration and elaborated a little.

Comment: Which version of sitecore did you try this with?

Comment: Hey...i've copied your configuration and I still get a null user...are there any other tests I can run to see whats going on?  If I run Sitecore.Context.Domain.GetUsers() I get no users.

Comment: Are you sure you have the any users. Have you tried downloading an empty security database and use that with an example user?

Comment: @Jens...I have a few thousand users in my db. The db i'm using is the same one that I use with my current website. I'm looking for the exact same user that I did in the original website.  I can send you my config files if you'd like...i sent you a private message in the sdn forum...if you reply with your email i can send you the files i'm using.

Comment: @Jens...I did notice one thing...when i run my sql profiler it's looking for my name with the applicationName as sitecore...but the application name of the users in my external db is something else....that could be the issue...can i change the application name somewhere in my code?

Comment: @Jens...i managed to get it to return the user...but I'm not sure if what I did was correct.

Comment: I changed the application name of my provider from sitecore to what it is in my external db(dangerous?) then in my code i make this call var user=Security.Membership.GetUser(Security.Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(email)) what i'm confused about if i pass email in by itself it returns a string extranet\username then I get the proper user however if i add extranet\email into GetUserNameByEmail the application name is sitecore and I don't get the correct user back why is that? If i leave extranet out of the email then how does it know which domain to use?

Comment: Great that you got it working! The applicationName isn't important in that matter. It is there to allow multiple applications to use the same database without conflicting in username/emails. Sitecore uses the Context.Domain to identify which provider to use through the switchingProvider. Therefore the prefix extranet is not important for Sitecore. It is only there to ensure you don't get clashes in naming through different domains. You set in your configuration (storeFullNames) whether it should store the domain in the username or not.

Comment: @Jens...one more question...if I don't want the users to show up in the UserManager...is there a way to accomplish this?  Reason being is that Sitecore shouldn't really care about what users login to my website...and I don't need the ability to block them from viewing any pages....

Comment: Hmmm.. You would either have to customize the user manager to exclude your domain or maybe you can just return 0 users in your GetAllUsers method. However I don't know the sideeffects of that

Comment: @Jens...I have 2 sites in the same sitecore instance...each site has it's own domain.  The reason they have there own domain is so that we can group roles in sitecore based on the domain.  Also, each site has it's own login...one site needs to authenticate against sitecore users and the other site needs to authenticate against an external db(like the solution above).  Is this possible?