# Sitecore extranet authentication

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I have a site that I'm trying to migrate into my Sitecore instance.  The Sitecore instance has multiple sites.  For the one site I'm trying to migrate over, there is a login page for external users to login.  I'm validating this against an external database.  This all works so far.  My issue is that I need to prevent the external users from accessing certain pages without logging in(they should be redirected to the login page).  The way that this was working when the site was outside of Sitecore was that there was forms authentication being done and when a page was trying to be accessed without the user being logged in the ReturnURL would be used to return the user to the proper page after login.

I'm not sure how to do this now that I have multiple sites inside of my sitecore instance.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This is not very different in Sitecore to how it was done before, except now you can control the security of which pages should be accessible by logged in users with the Sitecore Security Editor. There are a few pieces which you need to hook up in order to get this work properly though.

Have a read through these articles, they should provide everything you need to get this to work:

- [Implementing Sitecore Extranet login on a website](http://www.bolaky.net/post/Implementing-Sitecore-Extranet-login-on-a-website.aspx)
- [Setting Up a Sitecore Extranet](http://markstiles.net/Blog/2011/12/26/setting-up-a-sitecore-extranet.aspx) (site seems to be down, [view cached copy](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:C5WT_shd25sJ:markstiles.net/Blog/2011/12/26/setting-up-a-sitecore-extranet.aspx%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk))

Set the value of `<setting name="NoAccessUrl" value="/sitecore/service/noaccess.aspx" />` in web.config to your Login page (this can be an item in Sitecore) using a [patch config](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/05/All-About-Web-config-Include-Files-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx) and if a user tries to access a restricted page they will be redirected to this page, which will also include the return url parameter.

If you are using an external database to authenticate users then you will also need implement your own membership provider:

- [Sitecore authenticate users against external membership database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945187/sitecore-authenticate-users-against-external-membership-database)
- [Sitecore Membership Providers](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/60/membership_providers_sc62-a4.pdf)

Be sure to correctly set the `domain` attribute of your `<site>` definition to whatever you set in `domains.config` and set as the `providerName` of your `<provider>` definition.

Comment: Do you see any issues if on the pages that shouldn't be accessed without logging in, that I check if the user is logged in and if not I just redirect them to the login page?  That would be much easier for me.  I read the "Setting up a Sitecore Extranet" article and it seems to me atleast that when a user registers for the site that they need to be added to the role before they can actually log in.  I don't think that's the functionality I really want.

Comment: I don't see any issues with it, you could handle the redirect if needed but you could just programmatically add the user to the necessary role when they register. That way the security is set from within Sitecore and could be changed by Power Users, you could add/remove roles and sections of content as necessary and means nothing is hard coded.

Comment: oh ok..i appreciate your response. Thank you.  If I keep it the way it is currently, I set the return url by calling server.urlencode and attaching the LinkManager.GetItemUrl of the login page.  The problem with this is the url for the login page looks like this: http://mysite/login?ReturnUrl=http%3a%2f%2fsitecore%2fpage1%2fpage2%2fpage3%3fid%3d14.  Is there a way to get the url to look like a proper redirect url? instead of giving the whole path?

Comment: Check your `web.config` and check what you have set for the default `LinkManager`, in particular `alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false"`. You could always pass in new `UrlOptions` to `LinkManager.GetItemUrl` where that value is false otherwise.