# Membership for external users in Sitecore 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, sitecore, asp.net-membership, sitecore8

I want to build a user registration store for Sitecore 8 website. The users will go in an external database.

- Sitecore.NET 8.0 (rev. 150223)
- .NET Framework 4.0.30319.18052
- Razor Version=3.0.0.0
- MVC 5.2.3.0

Asp.net MVC comes with the membership built in (AccountController, views, etc). I wanted to port this to my Sitecore project. The problem is Sitecore also uses membership internally. I know there is a way for getting membership working for the Sitecore 6.x versions through the switching providers described at [Sitecore authenticate users against external membership database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6954337/421490).

Is it still the same process for Sitecore 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up not using the `SimpleMembership` and just going with `Membership`. I could not get the adapter that the `thecodeking` link mentions to work.

This method is not properly documented. I just had to change the config files. I did ***not*** have to create a custom class that inherits from `MembershipProvider`.

**Web.config:**

In `membership` section,

- change `realProviderName` to `"switcher"`
- copy `"sql"` node and change name and connectionStringName to `"external"`

In `switchingProviders` section,

- add `"external"` node with domains `"external"`

web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="sitecore" hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <!-- change realProviderName to "switcher" -->
    <add name="sitecore"
         type="Sitecore.Security.SitecoreMembershipProvider, Sitecore.Kernel"
         realProviderName="switcher"
         providerWildcard="%"
         raiseEvents="true"
         />
    <add name="sql"
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
         connectionStringName="core"
         applicationName="sitecore"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="256"
         />
    <add name="switcher"
         type="Sitecore.Security.SwitchingMembershipProvider, Sitecore.Kernel"
         applicationName="sitecore"
         mappings="switchingProviders/membership"
         />
    <!-- copy "sql" node and change name and connectionStringName to "external" -->
    <add name="external"
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
         connectionStringName="external"
         applicationName="sitecore"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="256"
         />
  </providers>
</membership>

<switchingProviders>
  <membership>
    <provider providerName="sql" storeFullNames="true" wildcard="%" domains="*" />
    <!-- add "external" node with domains "external" -->
    <provider providerName="external" storeFullNames="true" wildcard="%" domains="external" />
  </membership>
</switchingProviders>
```

**ConnectionStrings.config:**

- add connection `"external"`

config:

```
<add name="external" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

**Domains.config:**

- add domain `"external"`

config:

```
<domain name="external" ensureAnonymousUser="false" />
```

Then use the `"external"` provider directly which saves user to `external` db. This is the **key point**.

```
// uses "external" provider directly
Membership.Providers["external"].CreateUser(...)
```

Instead of this which saves to `core` db.

```
// uses default provider
Membership.CreateUser(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

This still applies to Sitecore 8 and the core asp.net membership features and the switching membership provider can still be used. The mongo db side of Sitecore 8 is for xDb, but you still use membership systems to authenticate.

I won't provide any further detail as the post you referenced seems to cover it all. Just in case there's another good post here:

https://himadritechblog.wordpress.com/2014/11/24/sitecore-custom-membership-provider/

Make sure you declare a new domain for you membership system in your domains.config.

Comment: I want to reuse the AccountController logic that the MVC project template gives. I followed the post and I get below exception. Can I use  SimpleMembershipProvider with Sitecore 8? Exception: `To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider". `

Comment: It looks like it should be ExtendedMembershipProvider. This may help - http://www.thecodeking.co.uk/2013/11/using-simplemembershipprovider-with.html#.VUXaU9q9KK0

Comment: As xoail has suggested, there are other simpler ways to authenticate and I would review each of the options against your requirements before plowing ahead with a membership provider. https://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2011/08/authentication-options-with-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to keep the membership logic very simple and away from custom providers. Sitecore has a concept of Virtual User that you can instantiate once you authenticate on the external DB. You can set any custom properties on this virtual user and let sitecore record it in xDB.
Here is a good [example](https://nsgocev.wordpress.com/2014/08/12/sitecore-user-authentication-against-external-system-using-virtual-users/).